# How to structure a search results page in AngularJS where the URL controls the search filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

I have a basic listing page where I list students. By default I'm listing all students with pagination. There are multiple filters I can set as well, such as student status, nationality, etc.

In my markup I have an empty div tag with ng-view. I do not actually use this tag with a template and it only sits in the markup so that the route provider will work.

In my javascript, I have a single controller called StudentListingController and it's assigned to the main bulk of the page.

All of the parameters for the filter are stored in a variable called filterData which is passed along when making an HTTP get request to update the list.

For example, when I change the page to page 2, I JSON encode the filterData param and throw it in the URL.

```
$location.path("/filter/" + $filter('json')($scope.filterData));
```

However, if I do a browser refresh, I want my page to remember the state of the filter and begin on page 2 (or with a particular student status, etc).

I currently have my route provider configured like so:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/filter/:filter', {
            template: null,
            controller: function($scope, $routeParams) {
                $scope.filterData = angular.fromJson($routeParams.filter);
                $scope.fetchStudents();
            }
        }).
        otherwise({
            template: null,
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.fetchStudents();
            }
        });

}]);
```

My problem is that this doesn't seem to work when I'm reloading the page with an already-set filter in the URL. Am I structuring my page properly to do what I want to do? I only have a single controller, but from many of the examples of the route provider online they usually show the usage of having a separate controller for each route. I'm not sure exactly how to structure my page to use multiple controllers for what I want to do. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: `controller` of `$routeProvider` is applied to template loaded into `ng-view`

Comment: @charlietfl In my example I'm not using a template with the ng-view and I'm just using an empty ng-view in order to get the $routeProvider to work. It seems like I'm not properly using ng-view with the $routeProvider but I'm not sure how to restructure the page :S

Comment: I would suggest studying the tutorial on angular docs site, going through it step by step. It is well worth the effort. Can also use it as a reference at any time to look at code for various parts of it

Answer (score 0):

If you have an endpoint that return a paginate/sort result you could use this AngularJS component to render in a table your data http://zizzamia.com/ng-tasty/#TableServerSide